# efficient date comparison in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame (actually a data table) that looks like

```
id  hire.date   survey.year
1   15-04-2003  2003
2   16-07-2001  2001
3   06-06-1980  2002  
4   17-08-1981  2001
```

I need to check if `hire.date` is less than say 31st March of `survey.year`. So I would end up with something like

```
id  hire.date   survey.year   emp31mar
1   15-04-2003  2003          FALSE
2   16-07-2001  2001          FALSE
3   06-06-1980  2002          TRUE
4   17-08-1981  2001          TRUE
```

I could always create an object holding March 31st of `survey.year` and then make the appropriate comparison like so

```
mar31 = as.Date(paste0("31-03-", as.character(myData$survey.year)), "%d-%m-%Y")

myData$emp31 = myData$hiredate < mar31
```

but creating the object `mar31` is consuming too much time because `myData` is large-ish (think tens of millions of rows).

I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this -- a way that doesn't involve creating an object such as `mar31`?

Comment: I you want the quickest way to work on dates: you can make your dates a long like 20110305L, doing this you'll compare and lookup much quicker, and 31 march of 2010 is 20100000L + 0331...

Answer (score 0):

You could try the data.table methods for creating the column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,  emp31mar:= as.Date(hire.date, '%d-%m-%Y') <
             paste(survey.year, '03-31', sep="-")][]
#     id  hire.date survey.year emp31mar
#1:  1 15-04-2003        2003    FALSE
#2:  2 16-07-2001        2001    FALSE
#3:  3 06-06-1980        2002     TRUE
#4:  4 17-08-1981        2001     TRUE
```